# mdc-select choosing option via JS

Tags: javascript, material-components-web

I have an xml coming from sql server which is rendered by my XSL script. I am using the latest release of Material Components for the Web and the problem I have is that I don't seem to be able to set options in select menus via JS.
Here is my mdc-select:

```
<div id="bridgeSizeSelect" name="bridgeSize" class="mdc-select" role="listbox" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCSelect" style="width:22%;">
                                <div class="mdc-select__surface mdc-ripple-upgraded" tabindex="0" style="width: 141px; --mdc-ripple-fg-size:100.2px; --mdc-ripple-fg-scale:1.8576761430946644;">
                                  <div class="mdc-select__label">Bridge Size</div>
                                  <div class="mdc-select__selected-text"></div>
                                  <div class="mdc-select__bottom-line"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="mdc-menu mdc-select__menu">
                                  <ul class="mdc-list mdc-menu__items">
                                    <li class="mdc-list-item" role="option" id="XS" tabindex="0">
                                      XS: &lt;28 feet
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="mdc-list-item" role="option" id="S" tabindex="0">
                                      S: 28-35 feet
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="mdc-list-item" role="option" id="M" tabindex="0">
                                      M: 36-41 feet
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="mdc-list-item" role="option" id="ML" tabindex="0">
                                      ML: 42-50 feet
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="mdc-list-item" role="option" id="L" tabindex="0">
                                      L: 51-58 feet
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="mdc-list-item" role="option" id="XL" tabindex="0">
                                      XL: 59-70 feet
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="mdc-list-item" role="option" id="XXL" tabindex="0">
                                      XXL: 71-80 feet
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="mdc-list-item" role="option" id="XXXL" tabindex="0">
                                      XXXL: &gt;80 feet
                                    </li>                                                   
                                  </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

I have tried using the following JS:

```
const select = new mdc.select.MDCSelect(document.querySelector("#bridgeSizeSelect"));
select.value="<xsl:value-of select="Bridge_Size"/>";
```

where xsl:value-of select="Bridge_Size" can takes values like "XS", "S", etc but nothing happens.

I have also tried:

```
$("#bridgeSizeSelect").value="<xsl:value-of select="Bridge_Size"/>";
```

since my select is initialized when I load the page but again nothing happens.
Finally, I have tried:

```
var bridgeSelect=document.querySelector("#bridgeSizeSelect");
            var bridgeSelectInit = new mdc.select.MDCSelect(bridgeSelect);
            bridgeSelectInit.value="<xsl:value-of select="Bridge_Size"/>";
```

with no luck.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mdc-select` element has a couple of ways to set the selected value. One option is to set the value before the select is initialized by adding the `aria-selected` attribute to the html element you want selected.

https://codepen.io/williamernest/pen/xYabNq

Another option is to use `selectedIndex` to indicate which value should be  selected after the select has been initialized.

https://codepen.io/williamernest/pen/xYaboq

There's currently a bug where you have to add `mdc-select__label--float-above` to the label if pre-selecting an option, but that should be fixed soon.

Comment: these are both broken

Comment: @tobias-kolb 
Thanks for commenting about this. I've updated both codepens and pinned their version to 3.2.0 (the current latest) so it won't break in the future. The html structure changed a bit but all I did was copy the demo from the mdc-web readme for the select. Happy coding!

Comment: The aria-selected codepen is broken. Is there no way to set a select value before initializing?